# Flow error from Partner Community

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a flow that creates a Lead. From Salesforce i have no problem and the flow runs properly. However, from the community, i get this king of error:
Could not resolve 'Afm_Field_LegalEntity.Source_Choices.Partner Referral.selected'. You can say myField, myField.myChoice.selected, or myField.myChoice.input

The community user has permission to create Lead as well as permission to all the respective fields. What could be the mistake that i am making? Kind of weird since from salesforce i have no problem.

Comment: Is this field part a managed package that requires licensing?

Comment: Hi David and thank you. No it is not. It is just a custom field that i created.If for example i erase this field from the flow, i get this message "Could not resolve 'LastName_Field_Individual.Source_Choices.Partner Referral.selected'. You can say myField, myField.myChoice.selected, or myField.myChoice.input". For standard field...

Comment: check to make sure that in addition to having permission to use the fields, they also have permission to use any object that those fields lookup to.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to the problem! It was the fact that from the community i selected the setting for the flow to get displayed in 2 columns. When i change it to 1-column it worked like a charm! Anyhow, thank everyone for the suggestions.